Github changes didn't apply correctly
I've made and commited changes on github desktop but now i have merge conflicts and when i check the new changes i dont see them all. So github didnt picked all the changes i made in my folder. Why is this? can i find my changes back?
For example in this image you can see that it has an incoming change to add 'generador_id' which was something i added, but it didnt save the foreign key specifying what generador_id was.

I have errors like this on many files, where only some changes got saved and other didnt.
